# SSRS authentication in a MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a ASP.NET MVC project which connects to SSRS using `ReportingService2010` web service endpoints to retrieve and download reports.

Connection works fine using `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` when developing locally with Visual Studio running with admin privileges

When published to virtual directory or used with `NetworkCredential` with `domain\username` it doesn't work as expected. I added the windows system user in SSRS as a system administrator.

Current syntax which only works when running locally in Visual Studio with admin privileges.

```
ReportingService2010 service = new ReportingService2010();
service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
CatalogItem[] items = service.ListChildren(reportsFolderPath, true);
```

Is there a way to configure `domain\username` password with `NetworkCredential`

```
ReportingService2010 service = new ReportingService2010();
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("insharp", "abc123", "insharp-lenovo");
service.Credentials = credentials;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just add a user only (e.g. insharp-lenovo\insharp in site settings, you need to give that user "browser" rights, and maybe some more - for testing, just give the user all rights, then remove them step by step)

But instead of calling the SSRS web-service, why don't you just use the ReportViewer control in your application ? 
Nobody is ever going to configure SSRS for your application anyway, so don't set yourself up for failure. If configuration can be avoided, then it should be. Also then you're independent of the ReportServer installed at customer X, which is a good thing. 
Also, you don't want to be at the mercy of the installed SSRS-version. 
You can use it to export a report (latest version is reportviewer SSRS2016-preview):

You can find a complete example here:

https://github.com/ststeiger/ReportViewerWrapper

This is what you'll need to do for one report:
https://github.com/ststeiger/ReportViewerWrapper/blob/master/Embedded2016/Umzugsmitteilung.cs

**Edit:**
You only added the user in the site settings here:
[image: Site Settings]

**Now you need to give the user permissions in the folder settings tab**

[image: Folder Settings]

Then click on "Assign New Role", or whatever it is called in English.

[image: Folder Permissions]

Comment: Already added the user like that in the SSRS. But there is no `browser` right, just `System Administrator` and `System User`. Have to use the web service as the end user only wants fill in the required parameters for the report and just download the report in excel format.

Comment: @chanafdo: That's not enough - as I wrote, the user still needs the permissions on the folder settings.  Also, you can do the filters in your application, and then call ReportViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Locate your `reportsFolderPath` path in SSRS, and open Security settings for it (you can reach it through direct link or Manage > Security).
In Security tab you will see a list of users with their permissions, your user name should be here in order to give an access to list folder contents. If your user is present in the list, then click to Edit it and ensure all checkboxes are set. If user name is not present, then just add the new one, and check all checkboxes.